# Scrolling 2 fragment (one Fragment and one ListFragment) as one

Tags: android, scrollview, android-fragments

I have 2 complex fragments (one Fragment and, below it, one `ListFragment`) in an activity and I want to be able to scroll the entire screen so I can see the rest of the list content. I've tried putting the 2 fragments inside a `ScrollView` and it does scroll but the list fragment only shows the first row. After that, I keep scrolling but the screen is empty (shows no other list rows).

Anyone know what the problem is and/or how to solve it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to interept any scroll kind of action on the first fragment for the second - listfragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set first Fragment as a header of ListView in the second Fragment.

```
mySecondFragment.getListView().addHeaderView(containerOfFirstFragment).
```

Where containerOfFirstFragment is a View (layout) containg 1st Fragment.

Maybe there is a possibility to add header view another way, but I don't seek it.

Comment: I don't want to add the layout of the fragment as the header for the other one. The fragment has complex logic (CursorLoaders etc.) and is used in several other activities so moving all that logic inside one single fragment is complicated.

Comment: I don't say about "layout of fragment", I say about layout containing the fragment. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html , see section Layout and look at the first example.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I didn't expect this to work. But it does work.

Comment: Just like kaciula said, never thought this could work. Ill give it a shot tomorrow. Thnx for sharing

Comment: In addition to kaciula, if the logic isnt to complex(like downloading some data and present it.) I love to keep the logic just in the fragment and not in the activities, cause if you do that you can easily create new screen an just pop a fragment in.