# How to embed view of Fragment in the header of a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `FragmentActivity` where I'm dynamically adding `Fragment`s in my `onCreate`. I want a `Fragment` above a `ListFragment`. Of course, the first thing I tried was the fragments in one `LinearLayout` in one `ScrollView`, but then the `ListFragment` would only show one row at a time.

I found [Scrolling 2 fragment (one Fragment and one ListFragment) as one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410747/scrolling-2-fragment-one-fragment-and-one-listfragment-as-one), but I don't know how to get the parent view of the `Fragment` to add to the header view of the `ListFragment`. I obviously get an NPE when call `fragment.getView()` and `fragment.getView().getParent()` because I'm still in the `onCreate` of my activity, so the views haven't been initialized yet.

How can I put a `Fragment` above a `ListFragment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a layout that contains your first fragment, like so:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:name="your.fragment.YourFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

And then, in your ListFragment, add this layout as a header, like so:

```
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_user_fragment, null, false);
getListView().addHeaderView(header, null, true);
```

Comment: Thank you! I put this right before the `setListAdapter` in my ListFragment. I used `LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())` to get the inflater. I also had to `add` a Fragment to the layout instead of having it already in there in order to get the View created with some args.

Comment: If you need a LayoutInflater you can call `getActivity().getLayoutInflater()` ;)