# How can you dynamically add a fragment to a listview header?

Tags: android

I want to add a fragment to the header of my listview, which can be done by xml as in here:

[How to embed view of Fragment in the header of a ListFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677112/how-to-embed-view-of-fragment-in-the-header-of-a-listfragment)

But I want to pass arguments to this fragment, which as far as I can tell can only be done dynamically (e.g. `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add().commit()`)

So I'm tyring:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.my_fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
```

my_fragment_container is in the header, but I get:

```
No view found for id 0x7f0a0089 (com.twitter.android:id/my_fragment_container) for fragment MyFragment {423d3320 #4 id=0x7f0a0089}
```

Is it possible to dynamically add a fragment to a header? Or if I can only do it by xml, is there a way to pass arguments in to it (like `setArguments()`) ?

Comment: Try setting the header view as a `FrameLayout` and then add inside your fragment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thing is `ListView` attaches header view at some point later than `onResume()`.

So you've got to add fragment only *after* header view is added to the view hierarchy. Also, you need to remove fragment from `FragmentManager` in `onPause()`, because otherwise, upon coming back to this fragment, `FragmentManager` will still be aware of previously added fragment, and try to find view by `id` specified. If won't be available though until `ListView` attaches header view again.

There's also a gotcha. If you:

1. Scroll the list down
2. Click some item
3. Go to another screen / activity
4. Press HW back

Now `ListView` is positioned to look just as it did before leaving to screen in (3). However, `HeaderFragment` is not yet attached. Then, if you scroll up until header view becomes visible, it gets attached. Then we add `HeaderFragment` to the header view and header view's height changes. And then, strange things happen in the `ListView`. I've yet to resolve this.

If your `HeaderFragment` is of fixed height, you could set header view to be that high, and avoid this problem altogether.

Assuming you're showing `ListView` in a `Fragment`, here's how I resolved this:

```java
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

    private Fragment headerFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        headerFragment = HeaderFragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public final View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);

        ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
        View headerContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header_container);
        list.addHeaderView(headerContainer);

        headerContainer.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
            @Override public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {}
            @Override public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
                getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.list_header_container, headerFragment)
                    .commit();
            }
        });

        // Set adapter etc

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .remove(headerFragment)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

`list_header_container.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/list_header_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I ended up resolving this by setting the header from inflated xml. I put a custom fragment in the xml that sublcassed the fragment I really wanted and hardcoded the arguments in the constructor.

Comment: I have listview in a fragment.
I want to add a fragment into the header of the listview like child fragment.

I referred your solution

first time the solution works fine for me but when i click some list item and navigate to another fragment and comes back I am unable to find the id.

Comment: Which id are unable to find? I think first 3 paragraphs of the answer are specifically about this case. Or am I missing something?